# URL concatenation javascript for selected (or not) checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, url, get

I have this code for that "sends by" GET true or false concerning if a checkbox is checked or not:

```
var isChecked = document.myform.checkbox.checked ? 1 : 0;
var isChecked0 = document.myform.checkbox0.checked ? 1 : 0;
var isChecked1 = document.myform.checkbox1.checked ? 1 : 0;

xmlhttp.open("GET","roulette2.php?boxchecked=" + isChecked,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

The html goes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox" />00<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox0" value="checkbox" />0<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="checkbox" />1<br />
```

As you can se up there in:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","roulette2.php?boxchecked=" + isChecked,true);
```

This only verifies whether the first checkbox is clicked and not the other ones.

How can you modify the `xmlhttp.open` to vige the 3 checkboxes the "option to be checked".

Thanks in advance!!

Trufa

Comment: Yes it matters, any one of them can be checked individually or in any combination possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to send all checked states in one variable?

Concatenate the states in a string:

```
var dm = document.myform;
var isCheched = (dm.checkbox.checked ? "1" : "0")+
(dm.checkbox0.checked ? "1" : "0") +
(dm.checkbox1.checked ? "1" : "0");
```

You get 000 if none is checked 001 if chekbox is checked, and 111 if all is checked.

**UPDATE**

I looked at your code again, and saw roulette... Are you writing a roulette-game? Then this might be useful:

```
function submitRoulette( ) {
    var i,box;
    var boxes = document.getElementById("roulette").getElementsByTagName("input");
    var checked=[]; // We are going to conatenate the values in this array.

    for (i=0; i < boxes.length; ++i) {
        box = boxes[i];
        if (box.name=="b" && box.checked) {
            checked.push(box.value);
        }
    }

    checked = checked.join(""); // Converts the array to a string.

    xmlhttp.open("GET","roulette2.php?boxchecked=" + checked,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    return false; // Prevents the form from being submited the normal way
}
```

And with HTML markup like:

```
<form id="roulette" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return submitRoulette()">
<div>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="0" />0</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="-" />zero</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="z" />00</span>
</div>

<div>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="1" />1</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="2" />2</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="3" />3</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="b" />1-3</span>
</div>
[snip]
<div>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="V" />31</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="W" />32</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="X" />33</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="l" />31-33</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="Y" />34</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="Z" />35</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="a" />36</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="m" />34-36</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="n" />1..34</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="o" />2..35</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="p" />3..36</span>
</div>

<div>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="q" />1-12</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="r" />13-24</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="s" />25-36</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="t" />1-18</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="u" />19-36</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="v" />odd</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="w" />even</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="x" />red</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="y" />black</span>
</div>

<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

In your php-code you have to decode the values:

```
0-35 is 0-9,A-Z and 36 = a.
row 1 (1-3) = b, row 2 (4-6) = c ... row 12 (33-36) = m
col 1 (1..34) = n, col 2(2-24) = o, col 3(3-36) = p
1-12 = q, 13-24 = r, 25-36 = s
1-18 = t, 19-36 = u
odd = v, even = w
red = x, black = y
00 = x
0 or 00 = - (minus)
```

Comment: @Trufa: No problem, just happy to help. I hope the update will help you even more :)

Comment: @some you shouldnt have bothered!! thank you very much ill take a look! I´m am writing a php roulette game with a MySQL database so you can imagine it is not very interactive nor fun :) A little of AJAX to up the ante just a tiny bit! Thanks again you´ve been really too kind!!

Comment: @Trufa: No problem at all! If I had understood from the beginning that you had more than 3 checkboxes I would have given an example with a loop. By setting different values of the checkboxes, the string that is sent to your php-script is as short as possible; There is no need to send the status of checkboxes that isn't checked. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Btw, since each checkbox has it's own unique value, the order of the checkboxes isn't important. Just put them where you want.

Comment: @some that is gret, I did it with three on the first place because I dont "trust" my code very much, so if I have to test if when the 17 comes up it echoes "you won", its quite boring to have to actually guess the luck number out of 36 :) I know there might be clever ways test this but this the topic of my next question. So thanks again, youve been really very helpful!